# PHP Form - File Upload Field for Signup

Tags: php, forms

I have created a PHP signup form for visitors to fill and submit that asks for their basic information.

I am trying to accomplish the following two tasks;

1. Add Image/File Upload Field
2. Redirect them to a confirmation page

I have been unable to make it work. Below is what I have.

My Code

**HTML Form**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="signup.php"> 
Username: <input type="text" name="user">    
<br>Email: <input type="text" name="mail">
<br>Experience: <select name="exp"> <option value="beginner">Beginner</option> 
<option value="intermediate">Intermediate</option> <option value="advanced">Advanced</option> 
</select><br> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sign Up"> 
</form>
```

**Signup.php**

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['user'];

$email = $_POST['mail'];

$experience = $_POST['exp'];

//the data

$data = "$username | $email | $experience\n";


//open the file and choose the mode

$fh = fopen("users.txt", "a");

fwrite($fh, $data);


//close the file

fclose($fh);


print "User Submitted";

?>
```

Comment: I do not see input file field in your code. May be you need to look in to this http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you lack an input field in your HTML to begin with.
here's an example of a form for uploading files.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Once you've done that you're not quite there yet because your file is stored in a temporary folder, you will need to move the file to your uploads folder like so:

```
$target_file = "uploads/" . basename ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: If this answers your question please do mark this as an answer otherwise this question will stay marked as "Open".

You can mark an answer by clicking the gray little "check" to the left of an answer, when it turns green you've marked it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ta add an upload you need to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form tag,then add the upload field. For the Email field change the type to HTML5 type="email", this will do a little validaation check that it is in the correct format. At the bottom of the php file add a location header if all went well. You could put it all in one file with an if statement at the top.You should also sanitize your inputs

Answer (score 0):

this is a upload file script which will loop through all the data of a file and insert

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
            echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name']. "uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
            }

            $csv_file=$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
            $type=$_FILES['filename']['type'];


            $handle = fopen($csv_file, "r");

            $i=0;
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
            if($i>0) {

            $import="insert into `table_name`(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7)values('".addslashes($data[0])."','".addslashes($data[1])."','".addslashes($data[2])."','".addslashes($data[3])."','".addslashes($data[4])."','$data[5]','$data[6]')";

       mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
       }
       $i=1;
       }
       echo "Success";
       echo "<br>";
       echo $_FILES['filename']['type'];
        }   
 ?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="" id="">
Choose File:<br>
<input name="filename" type="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```